# How to update Samba to the latest release branch

Tags: update, security, samba

I configured a network share using the guidance found here:

http://raspberrypihq.com/how-to-share-a-folder-with-a-windows-computer-from-a-raspberry-pi/

But after everything was successfully configured and tested, I was dismayed to learn that an older release branch had been installed, leaving me [potentially vulnerable to attack](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2017/05/26/samba-exploit-not-quite-wannacry-for-linux-but-patch-anyway/):

> If you update your Samba version to 4.6.4 (4.5.10 or 4.4.14 if you are on older release branches), the exploit can’t be used...

I checked, and I'm running Samba v4.2.14:

```
root@RASPBERRY:/home/pi# aptitude show samba
Package: samba                           
State: installed
Automatically installed: no
Version: 2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u6
Priority: optional
Section: net
Maintainer: Debian Samba Maintainers <pkg-samba-maint@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: armhf
Uncompressed Size: 11.2 M
```

How can I update to the latest release branch?

I'm surprised at how difficult it is to find this. I would have thought it'd be a fairly common task.

Comment: You will likely have to download and install from source.

Comment: @SteveRobillard — OK, I'm game... how is that done?

Comment: Be warned you are going down a rabbitt hole if you plan to update every installed package to the latest version to prevent a security breach. What about the security issues introduced by the new version? Do you permit inbound connections from the internet to your Pi? Do you control the local LAN? Are you running a firewall on the Pi? on your router? Are you running intrusion detection software? How are you logging? Where are you logging? Do you even read the logs?  The samba.org wiki has all the info needed https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Build_Samba_from_Source

Comment: @SteveRobillard — Hoo boy. OK, I get you. Mostly I'm just trying to guard against this latest round of RansomWare by making sure I'm using the latest version of SMB. I tried forcing SMB2 using [this advice](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-configure-samba-to-use-smbv2-and-disable-smbv1-on-linux-or-unix/), but I'm not sure how to verify that it's actually working. Any tips on that would be appreciated.

Comment: smbd -V will print the version to your screen.

Comment: I am not suggesting you not upgrade I am just trying to point out three things 1) there is far more to securing a system than updating this one package 2) that proper security is a major task and requires and is not a one time task and 3) there is no such thing as a perfectly secure computer.

Comment: @SteveRobillard — `smbd -V` prints the Samba version. I'm looking for the SMB version.

Comment: @SteveRobillard — Appreciate the advice. We're in full agreement.

Comment: @SteveRobillard — OK, got it. The PowerShell `Get-SmbConnection` command gets the protocol version, contained in the `Dialect` property. Ref: [here](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-server-2012/checking-your-smb-version).

Comment: @SteveRobillard — `smbstatus` also shows the protocol version, but you have to connect to a share from a client first. That's what was throwing me off—I was running the command without having connected first.